# What's best way to pass different insances of object to multiple classes?

Tags: python, design-patterns

`States` class is a superclass for `Game` and `MainMenu` because they gonna use attributes with the same names. In the project I'm gonna use only one instance of `Game` and `MainMenu` class. `GameData` is a class which loads(from files) and store data like images, sounds etc. and it's attributes are read-only. I'd like to pass `GameData` object to the `Game` and `MainMenu` instances and I wonder, if my solution where I put it in the superclass is correct or there's maybe better way?

```
from game_data import GameData


class States:
    """Superclass for each state"""
    game_data = GameData()  # Is it correct and 'pythonic'?

    def __init__(self):
        self.done = False
        self.next = None
        self.quit = False
        self.previous = None


class Game(States):
    def __init__(self):
        States.__init__(self)

    def some_method(self):
        pass # Here I'm gonna use game_data


class MainMenu(States):
    def __init__(self):
        States.__init__(self)

    def some_method(self):
        pass # Here I'm gonna use game_data
```

Other solution but I think it's incorrect because it's not optimal(2 instances of GameData()):

```
from game_data import GameData


class States:
    """Superclass for each state"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.done = False
        self.next = None
        self.quit = False
        self.previous = None


class Game(States):
    def __init__(self):
        States.__init__(self)
        self.game_data = GameData()  # First instance

    def some_method(self):
        pass # Here I'm gonna use self.game_data


class MainMenu(States):
    def __init__(self):
        States.__init__(self)
        self.game_data = GameData()  # Second instance

    def some_method(self):
        pass # Here I'm gonna use self.game_data
```

Or maybe it should be passed as an argument?:

```
from game_data import GameData


class States:
    """Superclass for each state"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.done = False
        self.next = None
        self.quit = False
        self.previous = None


class Game(States):
    def __init__(self, game_data):  # As arg
        States.__init__(self)
        self.game_data = game_data  # Assignment
    def some_method(self):
        pass # Here I'm gonna use self.game_data


class MainMenu(States):
    def __init__(self, game_data):  # As arg
        States.__init__(self)
        self.game_data = game_data  # Assignment

    def some_method(self):
        pass # Here I'm gonna use self.game_data


game_data = GameData()
game = Game(game_data)
main_menu = MainMenu(game_data)
```

Is one of these solutions correct or it should be done in another way?

Comment: This question is actually pretty good one. I have udpated the title to conform the actual question, and added `design-patterns` tag as this is really related.

Answer (score 0):

It look to me that the `States` class seems to be for handling the game states and the `GameData` class as you said is a read-only class for images, sounds, etc.

So instead of initializing its object in the classes, you can just make the whole `GameData` class as a static class i.e. make every methods in the class as `@staticmethod`.

Then you can just import the `GameData` class and use its methods in the `MainMenu` and `Game` classes whenever needed using the syntax `GameData.some_static_method()`.

Comment: In the `MainMenu` and `Game` I'm gonna use attributes of `GameData`. Methods are private and called just in `GameData` __init__. For example one of the method loads images and store them in the dictionary self.__images.

Comment: Ok so you can move those attributes outside of the __init__ and just declare them in the class scope i.e. make them also static. Then they can be accessed through the static methods.